# C++ stringstream error: no match for operator<< for operand types std::string and const unsigned int

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have this function which receives a `const vector` of `<unsigned int, unsigned int>` pairs:

```
// Type definitions
typedef std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> IdsPair;
typedef std::vector<IdsPair> IdsPairList;
typedef IdsPairList::const_iterator IdsPairIterator;

void Foo(const IdsPairList myPairsList){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "List of ids: (";
    for(IdsPairIterator idPair = myPairsList.begin();
        idPair != myPairsList.end(); idPair++){
        ss << (idPair->first == myPairsList.begin()) ? "" : "," << idPair->first; // ERROR
    }
    ss << ")";
    std::string query = ss.str();
}
```

At the line selected with `// ERROR`, I am getting the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘const unsigned int’)
```

I have no clue what the problem is, since stringstream is supposed to convert the unsigned int to string.

Any help? I'm using C++98

Comment: Put this code : `(idPair->first == myPairsList.begin()) ? "" : ","` into parantheses.

Comment: "Beware of the ?: operator and enclose it in parentheses" - the first rule here http://cpphints.com/hints/1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ss << ((idPair->first == myPairsList.begin()) ? "" : ",") << idPair->first;
      ^                                                 ^
```

add parenthessis

Without them, this is what it tries to do:

```
ss << (idPair->first == myPairsList.begin()) ? "" : "," << idPair->first;
                                                    ~~~~^^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can see the [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)